# htaccess rewrite rules show an error in my error log file

Tags: .htaccess, logging, url-rewriting, rules

I have a website which depends on htaccess rewrite rules, i rewrite my URL's with a sequence like this:

```
www.example.com/games/car/play/123
```

**Actually there is no directories for:**

1. games
2. car
3. play

**Everyday i see my error log show tons of error line(s) says:**

```
File does not exist: /home/example.com/public_html/games
File does not exist: /home/example.com/public_html/car
File does not exist: /home/example.com/public_html/play
```

I don't know why Apache consider these fake directories as an actual real directories? i have in my htaccess these lines of rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^games/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/play/(.*)$ details.php?slug=$1&id=$2
```

Now Apache consider: games/slug/play/id as directories and it's not just a fake URL sequence. Also when i go down for lower page:

www.example.com/games/car
And
www.example.com/games

**It's already exists as URL but not a directory i see an error log says:**

```
File does not exist: /home/example.com/public_html/games/car
File does not exist: /home/example.com/public_html/games
```

How i can resolve this issue? I have tried everything poosible but still get tons of lines of errors in my error log.

Many thanks (and sorry for my bad English).

Comment: In your access.log do you see requests for `/games` or `/play` etc?

Comment: "I don't know why Apache consider these fake directories as an actual real directories?" - Because your `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not match any of those URLs and either you or someone else is linking to those URLs. If the pattern does not match then Apache has no choice but to try and request `/games` or `/car` etc. which naturally triggers a 404 Not Found. Are these other URLs supposed to be valid? And if so what should they map to?

Comment: @anubhava , yes i see too many log error(s) for /games or /play. those URL's are valid and map to category slug for the page: category_details.php , But for /play it doesn't map to anything.

Comment: That means you are getting some invalid http requests, that has nothing to do with rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off MultiViews and also add some condition checks.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^games/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/play/(.*)$ details.php?slug=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I'll try this then let you know if succeeded! Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much @Panama Jack, I cannot see any errors in the error log, all vanished after applying your awesome code :) Super